# Exception while integration OKHTTP2.5

Tags: android, android-asynctask, okhttp

I Just integrate OKHTTP2.5 in my Android application but after integration i am getting following exception in the application.

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
Process: com.testpoint, PID: 16397
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTransports(Ljava/util/List;)Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient; in class Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient' appears in /data/data/com.testpoint/files/instant-run/dex/slice-okhttp-2.5.0_f7c3855e345b00f0c70af04a10c2a1ce2468221a-classes.dex)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.HttpsHandler.newOkHttpClient(HttpsHandler.java:39)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.HttpHandler.openConnection(HttpHandler.java:30)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:479)
    at com.testpoint.client.AsyncHttpRequest.doInBackground(AsyncHttpRequest.java:190)
    at com.testpoint.client.AsyncHttpRequest.doInBackground(AsyncHttpRequest.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: can you post all dependencies you are using?

Comment: Are you using proguard ?

Comment: Are you using multidex?

Comment: Yes i am using proguard. i am using Okhttp2.5 ,okio and Url connection libraries which also include the Android libs.